# How do I select an element that hasn't been created yet?

Tags: javascript

Meaning I have a todo list project where click an add button that creates a div element with another add button inside. Easy enough. Now I want to select that button so that I can use it to add a text input form inside the newly created div element.

I'm assuming the reason it's not creating is because when I select the element it doesn't exist at the time?

```
const addButton = document.querySelector('.addButton');
const addListItem = document.querySelector('.addListItem');
const todoDiv = document.querySelectorAll('.todoDiv');

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('class', 'todoDiv');
    div.innerHTML = '<a href = "#" class = "addListItem"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></a>'
    document.body.appendChild(div);
});

addListItem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let inputBox = document.createElement('input');
    inputBox.setAttribute('type', 'text');
    document.todoDiv.appendChild(inputBox);
});
```

Here's my HTML as well just in case

```
<body>
    <div class="sideNav">
        <p class = "heading">&lt;/td&gt;</p>
        <a href = "#" class = "addButton sideButton"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class = "sideButton"><i class="fas fa-project-diagram fa-2x"></i></a> 
        <a href="#" class = "sideButton"><i class="fas fa-user fa-2x"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class = "sideButton"><i class="fas fa-cog fa-2x"></i></a>
    </div>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

The first event will create a div with a plus in it. After clicking the plus in the newly created div I want a text input form to appear. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: look up event delgation. thats how jquery works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed `querySelector` will return null if the targeted element is not there yet.

But in your case you can just add the event listener right after you create the element:

```
const addButton = document.querySelector('.addButton');

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.className = 'todoDiv';
    let addListItem = document.createElement('a'); // Create the anchor like this
    addListItem.className = 'addListItem';
    addListItem.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-plus fa-2x"></i>'
    todoDiv.appendChild(addListItem);
    document.body.appendChild(todoDiv);
    // Add event listener now that we have the element:
    addListItem.addEventListener('click', () => { 
        let inputBox = document.createElement('input');
        inputBox.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        todoDiv.appendChild(inputBox);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Is this the most efficient way to do this? Would targeting the parent elements with an event listener then using event.target be the better way to go? Also sorry if butchered that I'm just now learning about delegation!

Comment: With event delegation you will indeed have the (very tiny) additional overhead of identifying the event target, and its parent *during* the `addListItem` event handling. If you would implement both solutions, I think it will be hard to find any performance difference, given that a user's click takes more user-time than the code execution itself.